# Firebase cpp linking with clang++ android

Tags: android, firebase, qt, gcc, clang

I recently learnt that android is soon switching from gcc to clang and I compiled by download ndk 19.0 and the firebase 6.9.0. But when I try to build my project, I get a bunch of ~129 errors and I'm about to give up and continue using gcc( with gcc, everything is fine) here is my log

```
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fno-limit-debug-info -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -Wl,-soname,libuntitled4_armeabi-v7a.so -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libuntitled4_armeabi-v7a.so armeabi-v7a\hello.obj armeabi-v7a\main.obj armeabi-v7a\qrc_qml.obj armeabi-v7a\moc_hello.obj   D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5Quick_armeabi-v7a.so D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5Gui_armeabi-v7a.so D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5QmlModels_armeabi-v7a.so D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5Qml_armeabi-v7a.so D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5Network_armeabi-v7a.so D:/5.14/5.14.0/android/lib/libQt5Core_armeabi-v7a.so -lGLESv2   -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o)(.ARM.extab.text._ZN8firebase5MutexD2Ev+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o)(.ARM.extab.text._ZN8firebase4auth4Auth7GetAuthEPNS_3AppEPNS_10InitResultE+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o)(.ARM.extab.text._ZN8firebase9MutexLockD2Ev+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o)(.ARM.extab.text._ZN8firebase4auth4AuthC2EPNS_3AppEPv+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/string:2911: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/string:2915: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/auth.cc:function __clang_call_terminate: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/auth.cc:function __clang_call_terminate: error: undefined reference to 'std::terminate()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_allocate_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_throw'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_free_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::length_error'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::length_error'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_allocate_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_throw'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_free_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::length_error'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::length_error'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_allocate_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_throw'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_free_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::length_error'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::length_error'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_allocate_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_throw'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_free_exception'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::length_error'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::length_error'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:225: error: undefined reference to 'std::length_error::~length_error()'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/auth.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::AuthStateListener: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(auth.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/auth.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::IdTokenListener: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:236: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::out_of_range'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:236: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::out_of_range'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:236: error: undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1651: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1657: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_rethrow'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1658: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(credential_android.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/android/credential_android.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::PhoneAuthProvider::Listener: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(credential_android.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/android/credential_android.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::FederatedOAuthProvider: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(credential_android.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/android/credential_android.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::FederatedAuthProvider: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(user_android.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/android/user_android.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::User: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_auth.a(user_android.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_authandroid/firebase/auth/client/cpp/src/android/user_android.cc:typeinfo for firebase::auth::AndroidWrappedUserInfo: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(callback.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/firebase/app/client/cpp/src/callback.cc:typeinfo for firebase::callback::BlockingCallback: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/functional:1406: error: undefined reference to 'std::exception::~exception()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/functional:1391: error: undefined reference to 'std::exception::~exception()'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(reference_counted_future_impl.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/firebase/app/client/cpp/src/reference_counted_future_impl.cc:typeinfo for std::__ndk1::bad_function_call: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::exception'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(reference_counted_future_impl.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/firebase/app/client/cpp/src/reference_counted_future_impl.cc:vtable for std::__ndk1::bad_function_call: error: undefined reference to 'std::exception::~exception()'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(reference_counted_future_impl.cc.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/firebase/app/client/cpp/src/reference_counted_future_impl.cc:vtable for std::__ndk1::bad_function_call: error: undefined reference to 'std::exception::what() const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1651: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1657: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_rethrow'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1658: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:690: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::init(void*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:230: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/iosfwd:126: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:690: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::init(void*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:230: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/iosfwd:126: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:302: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:690: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::init(void*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:230: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:690: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::init(void*)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:230: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1657: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_rethrow'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__tree:1658: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:620: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::getloc() const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:212: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::use_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:756: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::getloc() const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:212: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::use_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:529: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:628: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:629: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::num_put<char, std::__ndk1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> > >::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:629: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ctype<char>::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:274: error: undefined reference to 'std::uncaught_exception()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:529: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:529: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:955: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:461: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::getloc() const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:212: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::use_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:756: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::getloc() const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:212: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::use_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ios:529: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:472: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:473: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::num_put<char, std::__ndk1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> > >::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:473: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ctype<char>::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:654: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:655: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::num_put<char, std::__ndk1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> > >::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:655: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ctype<char>::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:577: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::num_put<char, std::__ndk1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> > >::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:577: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ctype<char>::id'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(idl_parser.cpp.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/third_party/flatbuffers/src/idl_parser.cpp:typeinfo for std::__ndk1::basic_ios<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::__ndk1::ios_base'
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(idl_parser.cpp.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/third_party/flatbuffers/src/idl_parser.cpp:typeinfo for std::__ndk1::basic_istream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(idl_parser.cpp.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/third_party/flatbuffers/src/idl_parser.cpp:typeinfo for std::__ndk1::basic_ostream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
D:\fcpp\firebase_cpp_sdk\libs\android\armeabi-v7a\c++\libfirebase_app.a(idl_parser.cpp.o):/tmpfs/src/gfile/kokoro_appandroid/third_party/flatbuffers/src/idl_parser.cpp:typeinfo for std::__ndk1::basic_iostream<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char> >: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/ostream:349: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::ios_base::__set_failbit_and_consider_rethrow()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/fstream:960: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::bad_cast'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::bad_cast'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::bad_cast'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'typeinfo for std::bad_cast'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/typeinfo:203: error: undefined reference to 'std::bad_cast::~bad_cast()'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:147: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale(std::__ndk1::locale const&)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:204: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::has_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/streambuf:147: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::locale(std::__ndk1::locale const&)'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:204: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>::id'
/opt/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__locale:204: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>::id'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libuntitled4_armeabi-v7a.so] Error 1
00:56:30: The process "D:\mashmellow\ndk\19.2.5345600\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled4 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.0 for Android))
The kit Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.0 for Android) has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
00:56:30: Elapsed time: 00:07.
```

Im using Qt 5.14 i really need some help

Comment: Your build is somehow mixing NDK r19 and r16b, and probably libc++ and libstdc++. Which exact firebase package are you using, and how does your qmake .pro and gradle files look like?

Comment: i really donot understand what you by  "exact firebase package", but i downloaded my it one week back  meaning i have the latest package and i have been getting this error even when i didn`t have ndk-16 installed. [link files](https://github.com/sheepeoff/Qml-I-O)

Comment: "i really donot understand what you by "exact firebase package"" - i mean which specific file you've downloaded, and/or which gradle dependencies you've added. While you're not using NDK 16, the firebase package was probably built using it.

Comment: i thought the same, but if i build with ndk-16 (before i was building with ndk-19),  i get this error (  clang++.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [errorLog](https://github.com/sheepeoff/Qml-I-O/blob/master/errorLog.txt)

Comment: " gradle dependencies you've added"  Its actualy a firbase plugin with (Storage Databse Auth & Dynamic links)

Answer (score 0):

Same here, it 2504 errors in my case.....
I think we should try to use QtFirebase with .pro file (build as library) instead of .pri

Edited: Fixed at this moment. remove QMAKE_LFLAGS += -nostdlib++ in file `.pro` of application (BaseApp in my case) will help that

Comment: Wow! 2504 errors,  Have you tried to check your libraries, Or may be link your firebase package manually and make a clean build.

Comment: "Edited: Fixed at this moment. remove QMAKE_LFLAGS += -nostdlib++ will help that" frow where exactly